# Ansible: How can I deploy the roles on paralel to different hosts

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have the next main.yml, and I would like to run the roles one by one but in parallel for diferent hosts:
For example, first I would like to run "cluster-prerequisites" role on all the host in paralel, when it finish run the "docker" role etc..

```
- hosts: masters:private_agent:public_agent
  remote_user: "{{user}}"
  become: True
  serial: 1
  roles:
  - role: cluster_prerequisites

- hosts: bootstrap:masters:private_agent:public_agent
  remote_user: "{{user}}"
  become: True
  serial: 1
  roles:
  - role: docker

- hosts: bootstrap
  remote_user: "{{user}}"
  become: True
  serial: 1
  roles:
  - role: prepare_bootstrap

- hosts: masters
  remote_user: "{{user}}"
  become: True
  serial: 1
  roles:
  - role: run_masters

- hosts: private_agent
  remote_user: "{{user}}"
  become: True
  serial: 1
  roles:
  - role: run_private_agents

- hosts: public_agent
  remote_user: "{{user}}"
  become: True
  serial: 1
  roles:
  - role: run_public_agents
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Rolling Update Batch Size](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_delegation.html#rolling-update-batch-size) chapter:

> By default, Ansible will try to manage all of the machines referenced in a play in parallel. For a rolling updates use case, you can define how many hosts Ansible should manage at a single time by using the `serial` keyword...

So, if you remove `serial: 1` from your plays, Ansible will run tasks on all hosts in play in parallel.

By setting `serial: 1` you tell Ansible to take hosts one by one, and move to next one only when all tasks gets completed on previous one.

Usually you want to do serial runs on bunch of backend servers to update them in batches to prevent service downtime, because part of servers can still serve client's requests.